# Draw Rectangle on SurfaceView (H264 Decoding)

Tags: android, kotlin, surfaceview, h.264

I decode the data I get from the socket in android in H264 and show it in a surfaceview.
but I need to draw a rectangle on the surfaceview with the data I got from another port
The width, height, x and y coordinate information of the rectangle comes from the socket.
Does anyone know how I can draw a rectangle on the surfaceview with this information?

[surfaceview code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vWhY.png)

Answer (score 0):

try the below line of code

add this

```
 holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); with  
    holder.addCallback(this);  line
```

then add in onsurfaceChanged method

```
canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
canvas.drawColor(0,Mode.CLEAR);
//border's properties
paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

Comment: this didn't work for me, i came up with a blank black screen in the surfaceview area

Comment: Please try with Textureview instead of surfaceview it may help you, please click to below link for detail https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView